# push rejected to heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

getting this error I have installed all the installation process.
Was following this link to push my Heroku app https://www.codementor.io/@jamesezechukwu/how-to-deploy-django-app-on-heroku-dtsee04d4

getting gcc failed with command
I have even tried Heroku config: set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1 but it doesn't help
I am doing this for the first time sorry if it's a silly question.

```
C:\Users\great\Desktop\Covid-App\CovidApp>git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 86, done.
Counting objects: 100% (86/86), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (81/81), done.
Writing objects: 100% (86/86), 35.21 KiB | 1.17 MiB/s, done.
Total 86 (delta 13), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.5
remote: -----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:  !     Your Django version is nearing the end of its community support.
remote:  !     Upgrade to continue to receive security updates and for the best experience with Django.
remote:  !     For more information, check out https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions
remote:        Collecting dj-database-url==0.4.2
remote:          Downloading dj_database_url-0.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.6 kB)
remote:        Collecting Django==1.11.7
remote:          Downloading Django-1.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9 MB)
remote:        Collecting gunicorn==19.7.1
remote:          Downloading gunicorn-19.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (111 kB)
remote:        Collecting psycopg2==2.7.3.2
remote:          Downloading psycopg2-2.7.3.2.tar.gz (425 kB)
remote:        Collecting pytz==2017.3
remote:          Downloading pytz-2017.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (511 kB)
remote:        Collecting whitenoise==3.3.1
remote:          Downloading whitenoise-3.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
remote:        Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:           command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-hacx75yc
remote:               cwd: /tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/
remote:          Complete output (62 lines):
remote:          running bdist_wheel
remote:          running build
remote:          running build_py
remote:          creating build
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:          creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:          Skipping optional fixer: buffer
remote:          Skipping optional fixer: idioms
remote:          Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
remote:          Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
remote:          running build_ext
remote:          building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
remote:          creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
remote:          gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.7.3.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120400 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:          psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
remote:          psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:685:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState {aka struct _is}’
remote:               while (interp->next)
remote:                            ^~
remote:          error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2
remote:          Running setup.py clean for psycopg2
remote:        Failed to build psycopg2
remote:        Installing collected packages: dj-database-url, pytz, Django, gunicorn, psycopg2, whitenoise
remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for psycopg2: finished with status 'error'
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-c4ho0s2b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.8/psycopg2
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/
remote:            Complete output (62 lines):
remote:            running install
remote:            running build
remote:            running build_py
remote:            creating build
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/psycopg1.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2
remote:            creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_fast_executemany.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_replication.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_copy.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/dbapi20_tpc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_errcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_bugX000.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_connection.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_dates.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_async_keyword.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_extras_dictcursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_quote.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_psycopg2_dbapi20.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_lobject.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_bug_gc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_notify.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_async.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/testconfig.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_with.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_green.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_types_extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_module.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_types_basic.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_cancel.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            copying tests/test_cursor.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg2/tests
remote:            Skipping optional fixer: buffer
remote:            Skipping optional fixer: idioms
remote:            Skipping optional fixer: set_literal
remote:            Skipping optional fixer: ws_comma
remote:            running build_ext
remote:            building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8
remote:            creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg
remote:            gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -DPSYCOPG_DEFAULT_PYDATETIME=1 -DPSYCOPG_VERSION="2.7.3.2 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=120400 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/app/.heroku/python/include/python3.8 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/12/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.8/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
remote:            psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘psyco_is_main_interp’:
remote:            psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:685:18: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘PyInterpreterState {aka struct _is}’
remote:                 while (interp->next)
remote:                              ^~
remote:            error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-riakcxg7/psycopg2/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-c4ho0s2b/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.8/psycopg2 Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to covidappsavelife.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/covidappsavelife.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/covidappsavelife.git'
```

Comment: You have a sytax error in `psycopgmodule.c`.

Comment: @dan1st, it is very unlikely that OP wrote `psycopgmodule.c`, or should modify it.

Comment: OP, please [edit] your question and show your `requirements.txt`.